# Selenium WebDriver: wait for element to be present when locating with WebDriver.findElement is impossible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It's convenient to wait for an `WebElement` to be present with `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions`.

The problem is, **what if `WebElement.findElment` was the only possible way to locate the element , 'cause it has no id, no name, no unique class?**

`WebDriverWait`'s constructor accepts only `WebDriver` as arguments, not `WebElement`.

I've set the `implicitlyWait` time, so it seems not a good idea to use `try{} catch(NoSuchElementException e){}`, 'cause I don't want to wait that long time for this element.

**Here's the scenario:**

There's one web page with a form containing many `input` tags. Each `input` tag has a format requirement.

A dynamic `div` tag would be present after this `input` tag when the format requirement is not satisfied.

As there're so many `input` tags, I create a general method like:

```
public WebElement txtBox(String name) {
    return driver.findElement(By.name(name));
}
```

instead of creating a data member for each `input` tag.

Then I create a method `isValid` to check whether user inputs in some `input` are valid. All I should do in `isValid` is to check whether a `div` tag is present after `inputboxToCheck`, with code like this:

```
public boolean isValid(WebElement inputboxToCheck) {
    WebElementWait wait = new WebElementWait(inputboxToCheck, 1);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("./following-sibling::div")));
        return false;
    } catch (TimeOutException e) {
        return true;
    }    
}
```

`WebElementWait` is an imaginary (not exist) class which works the same way as `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Every web element will definitely have an Xpath and a CCS selector. Since use of xpath is not a good idea, use the css selector. If CSS selector is not unique then, get a list of all elements for that CSS selector and pick the desired web element from the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The WebElementWait class as metioned above:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.NotFoundException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class WebElementWait  extends FluentWait<WebElement>  {
    public final static long DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT = 500;

      public WebElementWait(WebElement element, long timeOutInSeconds) {
            this(element, new SystemClock(), Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER, timeOutInSeconds, DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT);
      }

      public WebElementWait(WebElement element, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis) {
            this(element, new SystemClock(), Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER, timeOutInSeconds, sleepInMillis);
      }

      protected WebElementWait(WebElement element, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds,
              long sleepTimeOut) {
            super(element, clock, sleeper);
            withTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            pollingEvery(sleepTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            ignoring(NotFoundException.class);
      }

}
```

It's the same as WebDriverWait, except that the `WebDriver` argument is replaced with `WebElement`.

Then, the isValid method:

```
//import com.google.common.base.Function;
    //import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;

public boolean isValid(WebElement e) {
    try {
        WebElementWait wait = new WebElementWait(e, 1);
        //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        //WebElement icon = 
        wait.until(new Function<WebElement, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebElement d) {
                        return d.findElement(By
                                .xpath("./following-sibling::div[class='invalid-icon']"));
                    }
                });
        return false;
    } catch (TimeoutException exception) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of the @SuppressWarnings if you remove the "icon" variable you aren't using anyways.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak yes, thanks. All that I want is to check whether a TimeOutException thrown or not, the assignment is unnecessary.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this help you, but it permits to wait element how much time do you want.

```
public WebElement findDynamicElement(By by, int timeOut) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    return element;
}

findDynamicElement(By.xpath("//body") , 30);
```

Answer (score 5):

A more universal variant of user2432405's solution would be using SearchContext type rather then WebElement:

```
public class SearchContextWait  extends FluentWait<SearchContext>  {
    ...
```

This allows to do waits on both WebDriver and WebElement similarly as the SearchContext interface is the ancestor of both WebDriver and WebElement. The isValid method needs adjustment too:

```
...
        WebElement icon = wait
                .until(new Function<SearchContext, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(SearchContext d) {
...
```

Unfortunately, you lose all conveniences of ExpectedConditions.xxxx() methods as they use the WebDriver interface internally.

Answer (score 2):

I found this blog: Checking for an element – exists?, visible?, present? - https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/checking-for-an-element-exists-visible-present/

And it brought up the differences between exists, visible, and present.

> - exists? – Returns whether this element actually exists.
> - present? – Returns true if the element exists and is visible on the page
> - visible? – If any parent element isn’t visible then we cannot write    to the element. The only reliable way to determine this is to iterate 
>     up the DOM element tree checking every element to make sure it’s
>     visible.

Exists will tell you if what you are searching for is anywhere in the DOM; however, `WebDriver` does not seem to have a built in way to check if an element exists similar to plain `driver.findElement(By.name(name))`.

And, as explained in the blog, **Exists** is not the same as **Present**. So I can't use `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)`

My solution: (looking for feedback here :)

```
public WebElement waitForElementExists(String selector, String timeout) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

    WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector));
        }
    });

    return element;
 }
```

Comment: If driver.findElement(By.name(name)) returns anything, then you can be assured it exists at this moment. Otherwise it would throw an error.