# What is the most efficient way to wait for a page element (xpath) to show up in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, performance-testing

I am using Java and Selenium Webdriver in order to test the functionalities of a single page web application.

For this reason, clearly, elements are injected and removed from the DOM dynamically.

I know I can wait for an element to be present in the DOM using similar code that is using WebDriverWait (very neat template I wrote slightly changing [GitHub](https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template)):

```
public void waitForElement() throws Exception {
    /*
    Inject the following snippet in any web page to test the method
    <button class="i-am-your-class" onclick="alert('Wow, you pressed the button!');">Press me</button>
     */
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // 10 can be reduced as per Test Specifications
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement response = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='i-am-your-class']")));
    response.click();
    System.out.println("*****************************************************************************");
    System.out.println(response);
    System.out.println(response.getText());

    driver.close();
}
```

What I would like to know is if this is also the more efficient way to obtain such result using an xpath.

I have been researching on Stackoverflow and several answers point in a similar direction but no answer is focused on efficiency / performances:

- [WebDriver - wait for element using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java)
- [Selenium WebDriver: wait for element to be present when locating with WebDriver.findElement is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851518/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-element-to-be-present-when-locating-with-webdriver)

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: The measurement of _efficient way_ will a lot depend on the method `enterSearchTerm()` where possibly you have used an _xpath_ and if the _xpath_ is optimized or not.

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense, @DebanjanB.

I've edited the answer with a more detailed example.

Comment: @Pitto : Is it compulsory for you to use xpath ? or you can go ahead with any locator ?

Comment: @cruisepandey
XPath is preferred but I am looking for the most efficient way to locate a new element in the DOM (created by Angular / React / anything).
So, if in your opinion XPath is not the way to go, I'd be happy to read your idea on the best way to obtain the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of facts which you need to consider as follows :

- `WebDriverWait()` for **100** shouldn't be a real-time waiter. Consider reducing it as per the *Test Specifications*. As an example, set it as 10 seconds :

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  ```
- Moving forward as you are invoking `click()` method so instead of *ExpectedConditions* as `visibilityOfElementLocated()` method use [**`elementToBeClickable()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method as follows :

  ```
  WebElement response = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='i-am-your-class']")));
  ```
- Optimize your *xpath* including the *tagName* as in `By.xpath("//tagName[@class='i-am-your-class']")`. As an example :

  ```
  By.xpath("//a[@class='i-am-your-class']")
  ```
- Optimize your code to invoke `click()` as soon as the element is returned through *WebDriverWait* as follows :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='i-am-your-class']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks, great share and fuel for thought.
Do you think it is a good idea to use WebDriverWait or it would be better to use FluentWait?

Comment: @Pitto WebdriverWait is the tailored version of FluentWait. So stay with WebdriverWait until and unless you exactly need FluentWait

Comment: Sorry for disturbing one lest time but...
Would this solution be better or it is the same?
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("i-am-your-id"));

Comment: @Pitto As a beginner you may opt to start with `implicitlyWait()` and `thread.sleep()`. Of-coarse `thread.sleep()` degrades your _Test Performance_ and _implicitlyWait()_ may die in fire soon. Moving forward make a transition to the optimized solution of **WebDriverWait**. Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: You totally clarified all my doubts, @DebanjanB !
WebDriverWait is then the real way to go, as I supposed.
Really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for what reason you have said **XPATH** is preferred. I would like to add something about locators.

The **XPATH** you have written in your code can be easily replaced by a `css selector`. Here is the example.

```
div[class='i-am-your-class']
```

Now the main question is why do you want to switch to different locators ?

- more efficiency.
- more fast as compared to xpath.
- more reliable.
- more performance.

You should always use locators in this order as suggested by **Selenium contributors**

1. **ID**
2. **name**
3. **className**
4. **linkText**
5. **partialLinkText**
6. **tagName**
7. **cssSelector**
8. **XPath**.

**Note** : Most of the time a cssSelector can replace Xpath, However Xpath has its own advantages which cssSelector do not provide.

For more reference you can go through this SO Link : [Xpath vs Css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Your CSS selector looks more like an XPath... ;). When you write any locator as `attribute='value'` that is an exact string match. That means that if the class isn't exactly and only `i-am-your-class` then it will not match. It would be better to write it as `div.i-am-your-class`. It's not only shorter and easier to read, it will match any `DIV` that contains that class but not restricted to only that class as a `class='value'` might.

Comment: @JeffC : yeah sure I’ll take that ! ;)